# How to get aggregate average result every minute

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a data collected every minute in the following format

id(autoincerement) | ts(timestamp - *nix format) | temp (float)

by the query:

```
select day(ts), avg(temp) as avg_1 from scores group by day(ts) order by day(ts) asc
```

I get the average value of temp column since the data has been populated.

by the query

```
select hour(ts), avg(temp) as avg_1 from scores group by hour(ts) order by hour(ts) asc
```

I get the results from 0 to 23

What I would like to get is the result for aggregated avg value of temp for all the range but by every minute of the day (0 - 1439), to see the change of the temperature per minute (but avg value from all the days in 0, 1, 2 minutes of the day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the average temperature on each minute of the day, I would execute the following query:

```
select 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) as hour_, 
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) as minute_, 
    avg(temp) as temp_
from scores
 group by EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts), EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts)
```

By doing so, you will be able to analyze the temperature on each pair of hour/minute of all days.

To represent everything as minutes, just do:

```
select 
    (A.hour_ * 60) + A.minute_ as time_,
    A.*
 from (    
    select 
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) as hour_, 
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) as minute_, 
       avg(temp) as temp_
      from scores
        group by EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts), EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts)

) A
```

Comment: Many thanks!, It is exactly a solution I was looking for. Just curious, is it possible to make a time representation from 0 to 1439 (it is not important but good to know if possible)

Comment: as simple as powerfull!